# Throwing a WebException while posting XML data using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebrequest in c#

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to get a response xml from the UIDAI data centers by sending an xml document  using HttpWebRequest and receiving it using HttpWebResponse in C#ASP.net web based application. I already checked it using a java application and it is working fine on their side but the web based application is throwing an exception

> *An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code*

Note:The web exception occurs on the 5th line from the last

Please suggest some methods to resolve this

```
public void SendForAuthentication()//user defined function for Sending and Receiving Requests
{
    string url = "http://auth.uidai.gov.in/1.6/public/9/9/MLTbKYcsgYMq1zgL3WMZYrnyvsarlljxpom2A-QTPc0Zud23shpnqPk";//the host address
    StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("D:\\test-signed.xml");//loading xml file to stream
    string XMLData = sr1.ReadToEnd();
    string Conn = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>";
    XMLData = Conn + XMLData;
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XMLData);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();//**here I am getting a webexception**
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
    string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
        reader.ReadToFollowing("title");


    File.WriteAllText("D:\\xml.xml", backstr);


}
```

edit:
The exception I get is "the operation has timed out" though I had increased the operation time

edit2:
The above code works fine there was actually a problem with my firewall

Comment: What is the `Message` property of the exception? Is there an `InnerException`?

Comment: @Richard 
It says that the connection has timed out. I increased the 'httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000000"'.When I tested sending an xml to the same url using a server engine provided by [link](www.requestmaker.com) it worked just fine

Comment: I would make use of something like Fiddler to see what is going on at the HTTP level: do the request's headers and body match what the service expects. Also, please update the question with the full details of the exception and your debugging steps.

Comment: When using fiddler,I get 3 processes which matches with the host name.
The first one gives a result:200 and says that it is encoded with response headers
Entity:content-length:2731
          content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8
 Miscellaneous:
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlc...
The second process also gives a HTTP/1.1 200 OK and the content length is changed and content type to application/json
The third one with transport 
content-encoding:qzip
Is there a different way to receive it

Comment: You need to use the right decoding options in the inspectors: look at the transformer tab of the lower (response) pane

Comment: It X-sourcefiles is actually showing this "C:\Users\Prannoy Noel Jada\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite2\Default.aspx"
The exception is the operation has timed out though I had increased the time
Are there any alternate methods for posting.

Comment: You need to compare in detail the request (headers, body) between a success and a failure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It hit me that my office might not allows such http calls to unknown url and on my private network it worked fine